# Installing ubuntu 16.04.1 on mac OS X Yosemite: no mountable file systems

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, macosx

I'm not a computer techy person, but I would like to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my macbook pro (OS X Yosemite, version 10.10.5) to run on my Virtual Box. I have tried reading other similar forums, watching youtube tutorials but I don't think I got my answers (at least I don't understand them) and was wondering if someone could help.

So what I have done so far is downloaded Ubuntu. When I go to open my download to install it, it gives me this error message:

```
The following disk images couldn't be opened
Image: ubuntu 16.04.1. Reason: no mountable file systems
```

I am unsure what to do to fix this. I don't want to dual boot my computer, I just want Ubuntu to run on my VB. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i did it:

1- go to
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and download the ISO from there

2-download Virtual Box. that i assume you already have it.

3-install Virtual Box.

4-then open Virtual Box and on the left top corner it should be a NEW bottom, so press it.

5-So when it opens you should type on the name i recommend on naming it "Linux - Ubuntu"(VB should recognize immediately that is Linux and is Ubuntu 64 bits version). and then you press next

6-then you can set the ram size so i recommend on putting it on 1024. press next

7-select the option that says "create a virtual hard drive now". press next

8-then select the first option VDI(Virtual Box Disk Image).Press next

9-select dynamically allocated. press next

10-the you select how much memory you want to use for your Virtual Machine. press next

`note: be sure you download the ISO of Ubuntu 16.04 for 64 bits`

11-after preparing for the installation, you can select the OS you want to run and press START on the top menu of Virtual Box.

12-it will ask you for the ISO you download so select it by pressing the folder image and showing where you ISO is. then press start

the it should start running the Virtual Machine with Ubuntu and you should be able to install Ubuntu just fine.

that is how i did it.
my recommendation is, i didn't liked the Virtual Machine with Ubuntu so i actually did a Dualboot and i totally loved it.

this is the video where i learn how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SbTXqPk_1Y

hope it works.